# How do I buy an Epic Breeding Island? 

Tags: dragonvale

I am having a rotten time breeding rare dragons...  How do I buy a breeding island?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the Islands menu, not the Buildings menu. You might have to scroll to see it. Make sure you're on the latest version as well, but I think it's always been there.

The Epic Breeding Island costs 125 gems. You can either buy the gems via an In App Purchase or earn them from Colosseum matches or gifts from friends.

Comment: Note that you have to spend gems, it is conceivable to save up via Colosseum and friend gifts, but it would take a long time.  Most just buy the EBI with real money. (I did).

Comment: @EBongo question was originally just about where to find the option, but I've edited to reference the cost too